# How create measurement error for my chart

Tags: excel, statistics

I never do that. I have chart like this:

[image]

In the picture we see two the same charts. Of which one is inverted.
X-axis show meter. I need to know what chance do I have to determine the meter for the data received.

How can i create  measurement error for this charts?

I read something about it but i dont know how to do that. 
If someone can tell me what steps I have to do i will very grateful.

Probably i think it should look like this:

[image]

I dont know it show 100% when blue is ~43 and orange ~70 and 20% when the values ​​are similar for a long time. But it should show something like this.

Comment: Please tell us expected output and what you did (code) to try to achieve this, the result you get and how this doesn't match the expected output.

Comment: I didnt try, because i havent studied that. I am programmer. 
I got such a task and it is hard for me. So i ask someone for help me. Give me link or tips what steps I have to take.

Comment: For us to be able to give you links and tips we should know what you want to achieve. At least to me this is not clear at the moment. Do you want to calculate measurement error from observations? Then not sure what the chart has to do with anything. 
Do you want to plot measurement errors on chart? 
... ?

Comment: I need to do chart which will show chance for calculation position when i get data for blue and oragne chart. For this charts chance should be small when data from blue charts are the same for more meters. I can drwa how it should probably look like.

Comment: you want to present error percentage. But percentage of what? Do you have the true/theoratical/expected values for those measurements?

Comment: measurements fluctuations?

Comment: so it's just measurement1 - measurement2 ? perhaps as a percentage of the average?
what's the question then?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Mabye one more time. I want to know when I am getting measurement 64 for blue and oragne. How can I be sure it's 6 meters? If it is needed we can for example assume Absolute error equals 3.